# Deploy a Web Application on IIS 7

Tags: iis, deployment, iis-7

I have two computers - Computer1 and Computer2. I deployed my web application on IIS 7 in Computer1. I have access to it from browser in Computer1 by http://localhost/home.aspx, but I don't have access to this web application from Computer2 by http://computer1/home.aspx. What should I do to have access to it from Computer2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe firewall creates problems.